# How to pass a list of numbers to a postgresql function using Springboot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a postgresql's function which receive as one of his arguments a list of bigint. I trying to call it from my Springboot application, but I don't know how to pass the list.

My postgresql function is something like below:

```sql
public.delete_organization_info(orgid bigint, orgdataids bigint[], orginfotype character varying)
```

Here is the call of the function from my Springboot repository:

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT 'OK' from delete_organization_info(:orgId, :orgInfoIds, :orgInfoType)")
String deleteOrganizationInfoUsingDatabaseFunc(@Param("orgId") Long orgId,
                                               @Param("orgInfoIds") List<Long> orgInfoIds,
                                               @Param("orgInfoType") String orgInfoType);
```

When I execute the function with an empty list everything works OK, but if a fill the list, an error is throwed

```
function delete_organization_info(bigint, bigint, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Can anyone help to know how can I do this

Comment: Can you try adding parantheses to the array parameter? `SELECT 'OK' from delete_organization_info(:orgId, (:orgInfoIds), :orgInfoType)`. I have a similar case where I use something like `WHERE bank_transaction.id IN (:ids) AND ...` I am not sure how it works in the function calls but you may give it a try.

Comment: Another tip: try listen to the error message and add explicit type cast: `SELECT 'OK' from delete_organization_info(:orgId, :orgInfoIds::bigint[], :orgInfoType)`. Or combine the parantheses *and* type cast :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I finally found how to do it:

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT 'OK' from delete_organization_info(:orgId, cast(string_to_array(cast(:orgInfoIds as varchar) , ',') as bigint[]), :orgInfoType)")
String deleteOrganizationInfoUsingDatabaseFunc(@Param("orgId") Long orgId,
                                                   @Param("orgInfoIds") String orgInfoIds,
                                                   @Param("orgInfoType") String orgInfoType);
```